# Setup Debug logs for Guest users

Tags: debug

When establishing community, the actions of visitors such as self registration is not captured by default

How to setup debug logs for guest user of communities is important to trouble shoot the issues

Comment: Wow... question and answer posted at same time and by the same person. This doesn't seems to be right thing to do.

Comment: @RohitMourya Ask-and-answer is fine, and is actually encouraged. When it's a question that already has received a lot of attention and is already solved, that's a bit of a different story.

Answer (score 0):

- In browser, execute command below
  document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com";

Note: you can use developer tools within browser

- Locate the guest user name via Setup->Sites->Community Name->Public Access Settings | View Users
- With given guest user name,  setup debug logs via Setup->Debug Logs->New

Optional: sometimes you may want to add some debugging code in CommunitiesSelfRegController class